# Match rows between dataframes and preserve order

Tags: python, pandas

I work in `python` and `pandas`.

Let's suppose that I have a dataframe like that **(INPUT)**:

```
    A   B   C
0   2   8   6
1   5   2   5
2   3   4   9
3   5   1   1
```

I want to process it to finally get a new dataframe which looks like that **(EXPECTED OUTPUT)**:

```
    A   B   C
0   2   7   NaN
1   5   1   1
2   3   3   NaN
3   5   0   NaN
```

To manage this I do the following:

```
columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']
data_1 = [[2, 5, 3, 5], [8, 2, 4, 1], [6, 5, 9, 1]]
data_1 = np.array(data_1).T
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data_1, columns=columns)

df_2 = df_1
df_2['B'] -= 1
df_2['C'] = np.nan
```

`df_2` looks like that for now:

```
    A   B   C
0   2   7   NaN
1   5   1   NaN
2   3   3   NaN
3   5   0   NaN
```

Now I want to do a matching/merging between `df_1` and `df_2` with using as keys the columns `A` and `B`.

I tried with `isin()` to do this:

```
df_temp = df_1[df_1[['A', 'B']].isin(df_2[['A', 'B']])]
df_2.iloc[df_temp.index] = df_temp
```

but it gives me back the same `df_2` as before without matching the common row `5   1   1` for `A`, `B`, `C` respectively:

```
    A   B   C
0   2   7   NaN
1   5   1   NaN
2   3   3   NaN
3   5   0   NaN
```

How can I do this properly?

By the way, just to be clear, the matching should not be done like

- 1st row of df1 - 1st row of df1
- 2nd row of df1 - 2nd row of df2
- 3rd row of df1 - 3rd row of df2
- ...

But it has to be done as:

- any row of df1 - any row of df2

based on the specified columns as keys.

I think that this is why `isin()` above at my code does not work since it does the filtering/matching in the former way.

On the other hand, `.merge()` can do the matching in the latter way but it does not preserve the order of the rows in the way I want and it is pretty tricky or inefficient to fix that.

Finally, keep in mind that with my actual dataframes way more than only 2 columns (e.g. 15) will be used as keys for the matching so it is better that you come up with something concise even for bigger dataframes.

**P.S.**

See my answer below.

Comment: @G.Anderson, yes but the matching should not be done like 1st row of df1 - 1st row of df1, 2nd row of df1 - 2nd row of df2, 3rd row of df1 - 3rd row of df2, ... But it has to be done as any row of df1 - any row of df2 based on the specified columns. Does this help? It is more like a merging but with the order of the rows preserved in the way I show above.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone (I do not remember his username) suggested the following (which I think works) and then he deleted his post for some reason (??!):

```
df_2=df_2.set_index(['A','B'])

temp = df_1.set_index(['A','B'])

df_2.update(temp)

df_2.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my suggestion using a lambda function in apply. Should be easily scalable to more columns to compare (just adjust cols_to_compare accordingly). By the way, when generating df_2, be sure to copy df_1, otherwise changes in df_2 will carry over to df_1 as well.
So generating the data first:

```
columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']
data_1 = [[2, 5, 3, 5], [8, 2, 4, 1], [6, 5, 9, 1]]
data_1 = np.array(data_1).T
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data_1, columns=columns)

df_2 = df_1.copy()  # Be sure to create a copy here
df_2['B'] -= 1
df_2['C'] = np.nan
```

an now we 'scan' `df_1` for the rows of interest:

```
cols_to_compare = ['A', 'B']
df_2['C'] = df_2.apply(lambda x: 1 if any((df_1.loc[:, cols_to_compare].values[:]==x[cols_to_compare].values).all(1)) else np.nan, axis=1)
```

What is does is check whether the values in the current row are also like this in any row in the concerning columns of df_1.
The output is:

```
   A  B    C
0  2  7  NaN
1  5  1  1.0
2  3  3  NaN
3  5  0  NaN
```

Answer (score -1):

You can accomplish this using two for loops:

```
for row in df_2.iterrows():
    for row2 in df_1.iterrows():
        if [row[1]['A'],row[1]['B']] == [row2[1]['A'],row2[1]['B']]:
            df_2['C'].iloc[row[0]] = row2[1]['C']
```

Comment: Sure I know but I am looking for much more efficient and pandas-ish ways.

Comment: @PoeteMaudit that is no reason to downvote... If that is what you wanted you should mention it in the question.

Answer (score -1):

Just modify your below line:

`df_temp = df_1[df_1[['A', 'B']].isin(df_2[['A', 'B']])]`

with:

`df_1[df_1['A'].isin(df_2['A']) & df_1['B'].isin(df_2['B'])]`

It works fine!!

Comment: Cool but what if I have let's say 20 columns as keys? Will I write a big line for all of them.

Comment: and it does not give back the dataframe with the rows in the order I want.